# Find line with some word and without some other

Tags: java, regex

I search a way with regex and java to find line of a text with some word and without some other.

Example, i would like to get line who contain both word ice and snow but do not contain tree and ski. Word order is not important.

I beginned to fine line with ice and snow

```
(ice)*(snow)
```

That seem to work but if the order is inverted, that don't work.

edit:

is it possible to return word who have 3 letters or more between the word ice and snow

Comment: That's not really something regexes excel at. Especially considering how trivial (and faster) it is to implement this with string search..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @RanRag that regex is overkill in this case, but here's how it could be done anyway:

```
(?=.*\bice\b)(?=.*\bsnow\b)(?!.*\btree\b)(?!.*\bski\b)
```

`(?=...)` is a positive lookahead and `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. The regex also uses the word boundary `\b` so that it won't match parts of words.

Comment: it seem to have a problem. i tried with a file who contain this text:    hello ice snow
test snow
ice snow tree ski
snow ice ski tree
test snow ice  i scan this file line by line... and the matcher is found 13 times..... is supposed to be found only 2 times....

Comment: I can't tell from your comment what the file contains, line by line.

Answer (score 2):

I think `regex` will be an overkill in this case, just use [`String.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method of `String` class.

```
String str = "line contains ice and snow";
if(str.contains("ice") && str.contains("snow"))
        System.out.println("contains both");
else
        System.out.println("does not contain both");
```

Output = `contains both`

```
String str = "line contains ice";
if(str.contains("ice") && str.contains("snow"))
        System.out.println("contains both");
else
        System.out.println("does not contain both");
```

Output = `does not contain both`

Comment: using string was my first choice, but i want to improve my knowledge about regex, also a lot of code is needed